# How to get the value for jXDatePicker and store the user's selected date into the oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{

```
       if (evt.getSource() == jButton3)
        {
           int x = 0;
           String s1 = jTextField12.getText();
           String s2 = jTextField13.getText(); 
           Date s3 = jXDatePicker15.getDate();//**Here i need a correct code to store the user's selected date into the database**.

  try
     {
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe", "Raju", "1209");
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into NEWFRAME values(?,?,?)");
  ps.setString(1, s1);
  ps.setString(2, s2);
  ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) s3);//Here also i need some correct code.
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
  x++;
  if (x > 0) 
            {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jButton3, "Data Saved Successfully");

          }
        }
```

catch (Exception ex) 
           {
            System.out.println(ex);
            }
         }

Comment: what's the type of `jXDatePicker15`? Why are you asking same question again and again?

Comment: because i need a answer for this question.....help me to get this

Comment: if i posted in a wrong format and wrong grammar means forgive me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get and Store the value for jXDatePicker into the oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913268/get-and-store-the-value-for-jxdatepicker-into-the-oracle-database)

Comment: Sorry guys dont mistake. i didnt able to find that. But now i got that question. Please tell me a best answer to complete that datepicker